# Are there ways to style or modify the Firefox tab group window?

Tags: css, firefox, customization, xul

Theres the `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` for the main browser window, which can be inspected using the DOM Inspector and then adjusted in the profiles `userChrome.css` file.

I would like to do to do something similar to the tab group window (CTRL+SHIFT+E) but could not find any info how to open it in a tab or access the DOM in any other way.

Did anyone do this before? Is it even possible that way or would I have to dig way deeper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab view is an `<iframe>` element displayed on top of the usual browser content, its address is `chrome://browser/content/tabview.html`. However, opening that in a new tab won't do you any good - it doesn't work in a tab. Instead you can inspect its contents while the tab view is open. If you have the [DOM Inspector extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) installed, open DOM Inspector first and switch to browser window to the tab groups view then. In DOM Inspector select menu File / Inspect Chrome Document / Group Your Tabs. That's your browser window (`browser.xul`), you still need to find the right `<iframe>` tag. For that search for the `tab-view` ID. Once you've found the `<iframe>` tag you can expand it and inspect the structure of its document.

Comment: Wow thanks for the precise description! Made a quick test changing the background for the tab-view, containers and tabs. Works just as expected. Thank you for this sweet little piece of Firefox magic. :)